# How to debug shared xamarin project for sql lite operation?

Tags: xamarin

We have common project which has written by c# and we are supporting both technology (IOS, Android). Now we are going to support offline manner in both as well. We want to debug the common project with the use of fetching data from sql lite, because i need some of the information from local storage during offline support. However I want to know is there any other way to debug the application in locally without adding any SDK project.

Edit : I do not want any Android/iOS sdk in my system to debug the shared Xamarin project. And I have to implement sqlite related offline features for Android/iOS app team.

Comment: Why won't unit testing work for you? (eg. NUnit). It can definitely use shared project.

Answer (score 0):

@Daniel thanks for your quick response.

We got the another solution like saving the sqlite file in external or internal storage of the device and we can able to see the tables, records through third party s/w sqlite browser. Thanks